# card shadow effect not working (due to hover not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the cards ('.card', '.card p' and '.card p:hover' classes) to darken their shadow after hovering over them with the cursor, sadly nothing is happening. The navigation bar's hover function works fine though. The javascript code is used to make the navigation bar follow you down as you scroll.If anyone has enough free time to help me fix this problem, then thanks.

Also there is another problem: If you run the code in chrome and maximise the window, you can't scroll to the very bottom (using windows 10). If you can fix this problem too, then thanks.

```js
$(function() {
  // Stick the #nav to the top of the window
  var navigation = $('.navigation');
  var navigationHomeY = navigation.offset().top;
  var isFixed = false;
  var $w = $(window);
  $w.scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
    var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navigationHomeY;
    if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
      navigation.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        marginright: 0
      });
      isFixed = true;
    } else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed) {
      navigation.css({
        position: 'relative',
        left: 0,
        marginright: 0
      });
      isFixed = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
{
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
  margin: 0%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 187%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  z-index: -2;
}

.card p {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.card:hover p {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: blue;
}

.navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 7.2%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px grey;
  z-index: 0;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: #cccccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navWrap {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.li a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.active {
  background-color: #3399ff;
}

.active:hover {
  background-color: #80bfff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

br.clearLeft {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<div class="header" ;>Hello</div>

<div class="navwrap">
  <div class="navigation" ;>
    <div class="li a" ;>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <br class="clearLeft" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" ;>
  <div class="card p" ;>
    <p>
      Example text
    </p>

    <p>
      Example text 2
    </p>

    <p>
      Example text 3
    </p>

    <p>
      Example text 4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `:hover` is not working because you are applying `z-index:-2` on `.card`...so better to remove it...

Also I has changed some of your css and html part to clean the code...

***Stack Snippet***

```js
//<![CDATA[ 
$(function() {
  // Stick the #nav to the top of the window
  var navigation = $('.navigation');
  var navigationHomeY = navigation.offset().top;
  var isFixed = false;
  var $w = $(window);
  $w.scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
    var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navigationHomeY;
    if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
      navigation.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        marginright: 0
      });
      isFixed = true;
    } else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed) {
      navigation.css({
        position: 'relative',
        left: 0,
        marginright: 0
      });
      isFixed = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
{
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
  margin: 0%;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 187%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.card p {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.card p:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: blue;
}

.navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 7.2%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px grey;
  z-index: 0;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: #cccccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navWrap {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.li a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.active {
  background-color: #3399ff;
}

.active:hover {
  background-color: #80bfff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

br.clearLeft {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

<div class="header" ;>Hello</div>

<div class="navwrap">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="li a">
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <br class="clearLeft" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <p>
    Example text
  </p>

  <p>
    Example text 2
  </p>

  <p>
    Example text 3
  </p>

  <p>
    Example text 4
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing my problem, if you know how to fix the scrolling issue, then I would be grateful. If you don't, then no worries.